# How I can insert my django model data in fields for edit a record

Tags: python, django, forms, model, record

I want to edit my product which all data is already in django model. When i add press the "edit" button in option a new form is open to edit a product but I don't know who to insert data in fields. Kindly give me guidance how i display me data in fields [there is the image of my product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkB80.png)

[and that is edit form if you see before the edit button data is displaying but i want that data in form fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovz13.png)

**views.py**

```
class EditProduct(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stock/editproduct.html'

    def get(self, request, product_id):
        productedit = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
        form = EditProductForm()
        args = {'form':form, 'productedit':productedit}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <h4>Edit Product!</h4>
    <hr/>

  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <h4>{{productedit.pro_name}}</h4>
    <p>{{productedit.companyName}}</p>
    <p>{{productedit.Sale_Price}}</p>
    <p>{{productedit.Quantity}}</p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Edit</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**form.py**

```
class EditProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('companyName', 'pro_name', 'Purchase_Price', 'Sale_Price', 'Quantity', 'Picture' )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['companyName'].label    = 'Company Name'
        self.fields['pro_name'].label       = 'Product Name'
        self.fields['Purchase_Price'].label = 'Purchase Price'
        self.fields['Sale_Price'].label     = 'Sale Price'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add an instance

views.py

```
    def get(self, request, product_id):
        productedit = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
        data=Product.objects.filter(id=product_id)
        form = EditProductForm(instance=data)
        args = {'form':form, 'productedit':productedit}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'
showing this error @Reddy

Comment: instead of "filter" we need to use "get"